# Get info from ip address

Tags: api, timezone, ip-address

i am using an [API](http://ipinfodb.com/) to get a timezone from ip address of the client ,  i have looked for many solution to get client timezone using [javascript](https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect/wiki/Home) but none of them is accurate any suggestion how to build this API .. or get timezone from client browser .

Comment: How accurate does this need to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect/wiki/Home) script does not do the trick?

You can try the demo [here](http://site.pageloom.com/automatic-timezone-detection-with-javascript).